# Difference installing SQL Server 2014 on stand alone vs. VM Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, clustering

I have installed SQL Server many times on standalone servers with DASD and SAN storage allocated to it.  We have a new Hyper-V Virtual machine Cluster set up for us by a third party IT shop.   I am planning to install SQL Server 2014 on it and would like advice on what I should look out for and what to keep in mind.
What things are different or additional tasks I should prepare for as compared to a simple install on a stand-alone server.

There are 2 nodes to each cluster one for fail over clustering.  Do i just need to install 1 instance of SQL server in 1 of the nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

edited answer based on the comments.

For a basic setup here are a few things that I do before getting to the actual SQL install

- Have two additional IPs / Host Names in mind for the Windows Cluster and the SQL Server VIP
- Have two Domain service accounts setup for the Engine and the Agent (Something like DOMAIN\sql.eng.svc and DOMAIN\sql.agt.svc)
- Enable the following Roles and Features (File Server, .Net Framework 3.5, Failover Clustering, Telnet Client)
- In Local Security Policy grant the DOMAIN\sql.eng.svc account "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks" and "Lock Pages in Memory"

Disks

This is totally dependant on your environment and everyone will have their own preferences but in an ideal world I tend to go for:

- One LUN for SQL Data (D:) Formatted with an Allocation Unit of 64K
- One LUN for SQL Logs (E:) Formatted with an Allocation Unit of 64K
- One LUN for SQL Backups (G:)
- One LUN for SQL TempDB (I:) Formatted with an Allocation Unit of 64K
- One LUN for Qourum (Q:)

Format the disks and bring them online on Node1.

Windows Cluster

Open Failover Cluster Manager and Validate the cluster with (Node1 and Node2). Once you are happy and there are no errors create the Cluster using the Windows Cluster IP / Host Name you set aside earlier.

As for Installing SQL Server run the installer on Node 1 choosing (New SQL Server failover cluster installation), once complete run the installer on the second node choosing the (Add node to a SQL Server failover cluster) install option.

Here is a decent enough guide on the process from a SQL perspective with screenshots - [link](http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2014-install-clustered-instance-step-step-13/).

One thing not covered in that guide is once done I would also enable Kerberos Authentication by running the below Set SPN commands

setspn -A MSSQLSvc/SQLCLUSTERNAME.DOMAINNAME:1433 DOMAIN\sql.eng.svc

setspn -A MSSQLSvc/SQLCLUSTERNAME.DOMAINNAME DOMAIN\sql.eng.svc

More info on SQL and SPN's here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191153%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

It goes without saying that the failover process should be tested, make sure all resources come up on each node. Do this a few times to get the hang of it.

Hopefully this at least gets you started.

Comment: Thanks Lawrage.  I have no background in building clusters and previously only the sys admins have done the installation. I just joined this company and the clusters have already been built waiting for the new DBA to install SQL Server 2014.    Looks like you have done the task before.  If you can point me to any white paper or documentation, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hey Josem, Are you needing a guide from a DBA perspective (setting up SQL) or from the infrastructure side (VM's and storage)?

Comment: Hi Lawrage,  I need a guide from DBA perspective on setting up SQL like any new options I need to know etc..  I have no control on the VM and SAN side as infrastructure sys admin will not let me touch them but the responsibility on installing the SQL server is on me.   I am thinking my previous knowledge on standalone server setup with dedicated disk is not much of help in a VM and shared storage SAN environment.  Should I still insist on separate physical disks for  Data, Log and TempDB or are they not required in a shared disk SAN environment ?

Comment: Hi Lawrage,  I was able to successfully instal our SQL Server 2014 into the hyper-v cluster.  Thanks for your advice.  I guess I was just lacking self confidence because in my previous jobs, SQL Server installation has always been done by the infrastructure team.    The only step I failed on and I have to keep this in mind as I need to install into another 3 clusters is that the cluster OU account needs the "create computer object" permission to create the virtual cluster.